# What Images are Required for Windows 10 App Store Submission?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-store

I'm in Visual Studio 2015, universal windows app, package.appxmanifest and I'm pretty shocked at how many images are required for just the icon. Not including the images for the splash screen, that's 39 images just for the icon aka logo (!)

Although there are 15 images that are designated as "recommended". Note that under "Store Logo" and "Badge Logo" and "Splash Screen" it doesn't say recommended on any of them (so I assume all of them are important?)

So my questions, especially to those of you who **have successfully submitted an app** to the Windows Store:

1. Should I fill out all 39 icons + 5 splash screens = 44 images? or should I just do the recommended ones? and if I do that what about the store logo and badge logo?
2. What is a Badge Logo and what is a Store Logo? Is that just the same image I used for the other logos before?
3. I'm assuming a Logo = Icon, correct me if I'm wrong

#### Square 71x71 Logo

```
284 x 284px recommended
142 x 142 px recommended
71  x 71 px recommended
107 x 107 px
89  x 89 px
```

#### Square 150x150 Logo

```
600 x 600 px recommended
300 x 300 px recommended
150 x 150 px recommended
225 x 225 px
188 x 188 px
```

#### Wide 310x150 Logo

```
1240 x 600 px recommended
620 x 300 px recommended
310 x 150 px recommended
465 x 225 px
388 x 188 px
```

#### Square 310x310 Logo

```
1240 x 1240 px recommended
620 x 620 px recommended
310 x 310 px recommended
465 x 465 px
388 x 388 px
```

#### Square 44x44 Logo

```
176 x 176 px recommended
88 x 88 px recommended
44 x 44 px recommended
66 x 66 px
55 x 55 px
256 x 256 px
48 x 48px
24 x 24px
16 x 16px
```

#### Store Logo

```
200 x 200 px
100 x 100 px
75 x 75 px
63 x 63 px
50 x 50px
```

#### Badge Logo

```
96 x 96 px
48 x 48 px
36 x 36 px
30 x 30 px
24 x 24 px
```

#### Splash Screen

```
2480 x 1200 px
1240 x 600 px 
930 x 450 px  
775 x 375 px
620 x 300 px
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In direct response to the titled question, there are only certain images that are actually required and these are:

- Square150x150Logo
- Square44x44Logo
- StoreLogo

For the most part, anything that says Logo will be your apps logo which will display in various ways on tiles. The StoreLogo is specifically for the Windows Store and how it shows there. The others are the ones that show when the app is installed on the device.

For the minimum, you should at least support the Scale 100 images for these however it is recommended that you create visual assets for the 100, 200 and 400 scale factors as these work best on all resolutions.

Slide 19 onwards covers this in a presentation I gave on [Creating Unique Responsive Experiences for Windows 10](http://jamescroft.co.uk/portfolio/creating-unique-responsive-experiences-for-windows-10/) may give you some insight as to why its best. Basically, if you're app is running on a display with scale factor 100, it will use the 100 assets. < 100 to 200 will use the 200 scale assets and then 200+ will use the 400 scaled assets.

The other tile assets in the manifest just add to the experience when resizing the tile. They aren't required but I'd recommend adding them if you feel that the user would benefit from them.

If you provide a badge logo, that logo requires that you use lock screen notifications with your app. An example of these are the icons you see on your lock screen with the count of notifications.

And splash screen is the image that is displayed in the center of your apps window as it loads. Most apps tend to put this in and I would recommend it. Again following the scale factors as before.

If you need more help or info, I'm happy to lend a hand.

Comment: Hey I appreciate your response. But if you see above the 3 questions I asked does Logo=Icon? and what is a Badge Logo? Also, where did you read that you only need 150x150,44x44,storelogo. that seems to be a very small subset of the images there.

Comment: @foreyez I thought my edited response covered some of these, should have made it a bit clearer.

So, Logo is the Icon if you want to think of it in that sense. So when you see a pinned tile, what you see on that tile is the Logo. 

A Badge is the icon that's shown on the lockscreen.

And those images are just the mandatory images that are required in the manifest. If you remove all of the icons you have in the manifest, they are they only ones it says are required to exist.

The reason is the 44 is your small tile, 150 is you normal tile and StoreLogo is shown in the store.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of images required.  I have a [GitHub project with shell scripts to produce them all with ImageMagick](https://github.com/robertdknight/app-images-windows-store) if you start with a high resolution source in a wide format and a square format. It creates about 50 or so images, and stores them in easy to identify directories based on the categories shown in Visual Studio.